# Notificaction about a specific message received at a certain time interval

Tags: microsoft-outlook, auto-reply

How do I make a rule in our data mailbox (using OUTLOOK), that will do the following:

For each and every message that meets all of the conditions (1-3 together):

1. message contains a specific word in the subject field
2. message was sent from the specific sender
3. message was received in specific time interval during the day, e.g. 4pm - 5pm (no matter what weekday)

I would like the mailbox to send a copy of such a message to another specified mailbox. Is it possible to set such a rule in the Outlook?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Can you explain why? Points 1 and 2 are easy, built into Outlook, point 3 not so easy!

Comment: Not checked if possible: Launch a VBA-macro on the first two, to check for the third and send the mail?